# Qt - how to read data from a serial port in a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, serial-port, qthread

I'm new in Qt and have some troubles in using Qserialport.
I need to receive and manage data packets from an auto pilot and show them on a kind of compass.
but I don't know how to receive data in a thread and use them in my main program. 
I know how to use Qserialport and I did use thread before. but now I don't know how to use them together properly. 
I really need some example code. 
any answer can help. and sorry if my english language is not so good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read data in an asynchronous way. Just connect the `readyRead()` signal of `QSerialPort` to a slot. `readyRead()` is emitted whenever new data is available :

```
connect(&serial, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readData()));
```

`readData()` is a slot that is called everytime `QSerialPort` emits the `readyRead()` signal. `readData()` appends any available data to a `QByteArray` class member :

```
void MyClass::readData()
{
    receivedData.append(serial.readAll());

    if(receivedData.count()>=someAmount)
    {
        //Use data and remove used data from receivedData
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer it's really help. but i have another question. when i use readAll() it will read all incoming data and store them in QbyteArray, right? now how can i manage this data and pass some bytes of them to my main program parameters?

Comment: Yes you read all data and store it in a `QByteArray`. What do you mean by "main program parameters"?

Comment: the hole packet read in a thread and stored in QByteArray. now my question is how can I manage this for example 48 byte packet data and pass 4 bytes of it to for example a float in my UI?

Comment: and I have another question. in readData() i don't get what receivedData.append do? are you define receivedData else where?

Comment: `receivedData` is a class member of type `QByteArray`. You should define it in .h file. Converting some bytes to an other type like int depends on the endianness of the protocol. You can shift an int variable 8 bites and add a byte value to it and repeat it four times.